# Print a Html document to a pre selected printer with given page settings in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I need to print a Html document to a pre selected printer with page settings I provide. How would I do this using Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure if you want your Html document document as a Picture or the source code. But here is on try
Use this side: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/htmlastext.html
and Converte it to text, after you do so try to print it out on your home installed Printer.

Comment: If so, ask Google for "Html to PDF convert free online" so you can find Website converter. [link](http://pdfcrowd.com/) is one i found. And via PDF you can Print it. ^^ Good luck

Comment: Thanks. now tell me how would I do it programatically using Win Forms not to convert but to print